# Thingsboard-gateway logs.conf explained

Tags: python, logging, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

In Thingsboard-gateway is a logs.conf, i want to adjust the settings that way i got the leasest data in the log files.
Now i try to understand this part:

```
[handler_connectorHandler]
level=INFO
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=LogFormatter
args=("/var/log/thingsboard-gateway/connector.log", "d", 1, 7,)
```

What does the "d" mean and the "1" and the "7"
Is "d" daily and the "1" once a day?
And the "7" that there are 7 historical log files?

Answer (score 0):

you are right. 1 is an interval for file rotation and 7 historical files.
This configuration part relates to logging module, the full documentation about this is available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler).